# Compiling python modules with DEBUG defined on MSVC

Tags: python, debugging, visual-c++

Python rather stupidly has a pragma directive in its include files that forces a link against `python26_d.lib` when the `DEBUG` preprocessor variable is defined. This is a problem because the python installer doesn't come with `python26_d.lib`! So I can't build applications in MSVC in debug mode. If I temporarily `#undef DEBUG` for just one file I get many complaints about inconsistent DLL linkage. If I change the pragma in pythons include file I get undefined references to various debug functions.

I have tried compiling my own version of python but its somehow different enough from the python that gets distributed that I can't use my modules with apps built with the vanilla version of python

Can anyone give me any advice on how to get round this?

Comment: Can you create a debugging .lib file from the .dll via [dumpbin http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [python list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-March/1198717.html)

> As a workaround to the situation, try
>   to copy the file python26.dll to
>   python26_d.dll.  (I'm not sure this
>   will work; you say you are building a
>   SWIG library in debug mode, and it's
>   possible that SWIG will try to use
>   features of the Python debugging
>   version.  If that's the case, you'll
>   have no choice but to use the
>   debugging version of Python.)

Edit: From comments:

> You should also edit pyconfig.h and
>   comment out the line "#define
>   Py_DEBUG" (line 374)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I also get the unresolved externals if I do that.

Comment: AHA! But it does work if you also edit pyconfig.h and comment out the line "#define Py_DEBUG" (line 374). Then everything links fine. Its still annoying that you have to modify the install rather than your own code, but it works. I've selected your answer as the chosen answer, but it would be nice if you updated your answer with this tip, in case other people come looking as they won't expect part of the solution to be in a comment. Thanks!

Comment: @DaedalusFall: Put that instruction in an answer, I want to upvote it! Had the exact same problem and your solution seems to work fine.

Answer (score 8):

After you comment out "#define Py_DEBUG" on line 332 and modify

```
#   ifdef _DEBUG
#    pragma comment(lib,"python26_d.lib")
#   else
```

to

```
#   ifdef _DEBUG
#    pragma comment(lib,"python26.lib")
#   else
```

you do not need to python26_d.lib anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can also go the other way: switch to «Release» and then debug it. you need to enable generation of debugging symbols info in project properties in compiler and linker prefs; MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz(VS.71).aspx) will tell you exactly what options you need to set to debug a release build.

Answer (score 4):

Based on all answers I successfully disabled `_DEBUG` temporary:

```
#if _DEBUG
  #define _DEBUG_IS_ENABLED
  #undef _DEBUG
#endif
#include "pyconfig.h"
#if defined(_DEBUG_IS_ENABLED)
  #define _DEBUG
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

This works also when linking with static libraries.  I made a copy of python26.lib, and renamed it python26_d.lib.  I commented out the line #define PY_DEBUG in pyconfig.h. Also changed the pragma to "pragma comment(lib,"python26.lib")" on line 332.  Voila!  It worked.