# Need help extending Python 3.2 with C++ modules

Tags: c++, python, swig

Does anyone have suggestions for how to extend specifically Python 3 with C++? I've tried using SWIG but it comes up with a fatal link error when trying to access a library file that doesn't exist on my computer (Python_d.lib or something similar).

EDIT:

The steps I took were:

1) Downloading swigwin-2.0.4 from http://www.swig.org/download.html

2) Setting up the environment variables (PYTHON_INCLUDE and PYTHON_LIB)

3) Building one of the examples included with the swigwin package. The code for this is posted below. This was built in MVSC++ 2010.

```
/* File : example.c */

#include "example.h"
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846

/* Move the shape to a new location */
void Shape::move(double dx, double dy) {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

int Shape::nshapes = 0;

double Circle::area(void) {
    return M_PI*radius*radius;
}

double Circle::perimeter(void) {
    return 2*M_PI*radius;
}

double Square::area(void) {
    return width*width;
}

double Square::perimeter(void) {
    return 4*width;
}
```

The relevant part of output I get from this is:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\David\Downloads\swigwin-2.0.4\Examples\python\class\.\Debug\example.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\David\Downloads\swigwin-2.0.4\Examples\python\class\_example.pyd). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(991,5): warning MSB8012: TargetExt(.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (.pyd). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(992,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(example) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (_example). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).

1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python32_d.lib'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:04.27
```

Comment: Then please ask about solving that SWIG error (enter the details of what you did, with the relevant code and exact compiler error). Just because you couldn't get it to build doesn't mean it's not the right thing to use.

Comment: As @Mat says - if you post a concrete question (what the module interface looked like, what you ran to compile it, what the error message was) then people can fix that for you. As it stands this question is very vague and open-eneded.

Comment: That's true, I was at university at the time and didn't have the details handy, I just wanted to see what steps other people took to get Python 3 working with C++. I've appended all the information I can to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the build configuration from Debug to Release in MSVC, or check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1236060/222914).

Comment: Thanks very much, the project builds successfully now. The only issue I'm having now is that it's trying to reference a dll that doesn't exist for the example project I'm working with. I'll try to look into this one myself first, but if you know any solutions to this off the top of your head, I'd appreciate it a lot.

If you're interested:
"Unable to start program 'C:\Users....\swigwin-2.0.4\Examples\python\class\.\Release\example.dll'. The system can not find the file specified."

Comment: Check the linker input files in the project's properties.

Comment: Tagc, how did you resolve this?  I have the same error.  I think the point of the VS project is to generate example.dll... which isn't happening for me.

Comment: Never mind, the point of the VS project is to generate _example.pyd.  I fixed the error by going to Build > Rebuild Solution.