# PyODBC Cursor.fetchall() causes python to crash (segfault)

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, pyodbc

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows XP.

I have a simple python script on a schedule that uses pyodbc to grab data from an AR database which has worked perfectly until today.  I get a segfault once the cursor reaches a particular row.  I have similar code in C++ which has no problem retrieving the results, so I figure this is an issue with pyodbc.  Either way, I'd like to "catch" this error.  I've tried to use the subprocess module, but it doesn't seem to work since once the script hits a segfault it just hangs on the "python.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close." message.  I guess I could set some arbitrary time frame for it to complete in and, if it doesn't, force close the process, but that seems kind of lame.

I have reported the issue here as well - http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=278

@paulsm4 - I have answered your questions below, thanks!

> Q: You're on Windows/XP (32-bit, I imagine), Python 2.7, and BMC
>   Remedy AR. Correct?

A: Yes, it fails on Win XP 32 bit and Win Server 2008 R2 64 bit.

> Q: Is there any chance you (or perhaps your client, if they purchased
>   Remedy AR) can open a support call with BMC?

A: Probably not...

> Q: Can you isolate which column causes the segfault? "What's
>   different" when the segfault occurs?

A: Just this particular row...but I have now isolated the issue with your suggestions below. I used a loop to fetch each field until a segfault occurred.

```
cursor.columns(table="mytable")
result = cursor.fetchall()
columns = [x[3] for x in result]
for x in columns:
    print x
    cursor.execute("""select "{0}"
                      from "mytable"
                      where id = 'abc123'""".format(x))
    cursor.fetchall()
```

Once I identified the column that causes the segfault I tried a query for all columns EXCEPT that one and sure enough it worked no problem.

The column's data type was CHAR(1024). I used C++ to grab the data and noticed that the column for that row had the most characters in it out of any other row...1023! Thinking that maybe there is a buffer in the C code for PyODBC that is getting written to beyond its boundaries.

> 2) Enable ODBC tracing: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274551
>
> 3) Post back the results (including the log trace of the failure)

Ok, I have created a pastebin with the results of the ODBC trace - http://pastebin.com/6gt95rB8. To protect the innocent, I have masked some string values.

Looks like it may have been due to data truncation.

Does this give us enough info as to how to fix the issue?  I'm thinking it's a bug within PyODBC since using the C ODBC API directly works fine.

**Update**

So I compiled PyODBC for debugging and I got an interesting message -

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'tempBuffer' was corrupted.
```

While I don't currently understand it, the call stack is as follows -

```
pyodbc.pyd!GetDataString(Cursor * cur=0x00e47100, int iCol=0)  Line 410 + 0xf bytes C++
pyodbc.pyd!GetData(Cursor * cur=0x00e47100, int iCol=0)  Line 697 + 0xd bytes   C++
pyodbc.pyd!Cursor_fetch(Cursor * cur=0x00e47100)  Line 1032 + 0xd bytes C++
pyodbc.pyd!Cursor_fetchlist(Cursor * cur=0x00e47100, int max=-1)  Line 1063 + 0x9 bytes C++
pyodbc.pyd!Cursor_fetchall(_object * self=0x00e47100, _object * args=0x00000000)  Line 1142 + 0xb bytes C++
```

**Resolved!**

Problem was solved by ensuring that the buffer had enough space.

In `getdata.cpp` on line 330

```
char tempBuffer[1024];
```

Was changed to

```
char tempBuffer[1025];
```

Compiled and replaced the old pyodbc.pyd file in site-packages and we're all good!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi - I see you've posted here, on [PyODBC](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=278) and tried again on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713701/how-to-debug-c-extensions-for-python-on-windows).  Q: What is the underlying database?  Q: What row# is it crashing on?  What data item is it crashing on?  What happens if you delete that row?

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Underlying DB is BMC Remedy AR (Action Request).  I don't own the database, so I cannot make edits.  It's not a particular row number, it is a particular row.  For instance, if I query that row by its PK I get a segfault.  If I filter the row out (i.e. `where id <> 'abc123'`) I don't get a segfault.  If I query the DB directly in C++ with ODBC, I don't get any issues.

Comment: If you've got a working means of accessing the DB from C++, can you check the contents of the specific from there? Is there anything obviously wrong with the data in that row?

Comment: Nothing obvious stuck out, but I will check each of your questions tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: @pyrospade: you've got lots of suggestions between [your other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713701/how-to-debug-c-extensions-for-python-on-windows) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657958/pyodbc-cursor-fetchall-causes-python-to-crash-segfault).  Any luck yet?  Any new discoveries?

Comment: This might also be applicable: http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=188.  TWO OTHER SUGGESTIONS: 1) Download the very latest [PyODBC 3.0.6](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) if you haven't already, and 2) Download and install MS Data Access Components [MDAC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793)

Comment: I've updated my original question with my steps but unfortunately no, it's not working yet.  I am currently in the process of compiling PyODBC for debugging in VS2008 and am running into roadblocks there.  It is looking for python27_d.lib which I don't have currently...

Comment: Ok, looks like this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236060/compiling-python-modules-whith-debug-defined-on-msvc) helped.  Successfully compiled...let's see what happens!

Comment: @paulsm4 - updated my next steps in my answer...what should I do from here?  Should I/how can I get the PyODBC folks involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: You're on Windows/XP (32-bit, I imagine),  [Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/getit/), and [BMC Remedy AR](http://www.bmc.com/products/product-listing/22735072-106757-2391.html).  Correct?

Q: Is there any chance you (or perhaps your client, if they purchased Remedy AR) can open a support call with BMC?

Q: Can you isolate which column causes the segfault?  "What's different" when the segfault occurs?

Please do the following:

1) Try different "select a,b,c" statements using Python/ODBC to see if you can reproduce the problem (independent of your program) and isolate a specific column (or, ideally, a specific column and row!)

2) Enable ODBC tracing:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274551

3) Post back the results (including the log trace of the failure)

4) If that doesn't work - and if you can't get BMC Technical Support involved - then Plan B might be to debug at the ODBC library level:

- [How to debug C extensions for Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713701/how-to-debug-c-extensions-for-python-on-windows)

  Q: What C/C++ compiler would work best for you?

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I will edit the answer to make this easier to read.

Comment: @pyrospade Please edit your question to provide the answers instead. (Here's a link to your suggested edit, so that your typing isn't wasted: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/333611)

Answer (score 0):

for any one else who might get this error, check the data type format returned. in my case, it was a `datetime` column. used `select convert(varchar, getdate(), 20) from xxx`, or any `convert` formats to get your desired result.