# How to debug C extensions for Python on Windows

Tags: python, c, windows, debugging, gdb

I have a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657958/catching-a-segfault-in-python-pyodbc-cursor-fetch-causes-python-to-crash) with a segfault in pyodbc and would like to debug it in Windows XP x86.  However, the information online seems primarily Linux-centric.  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I admit I've never tried to debug a Python C extension on Windows, but have you tried attaching a debugger to the Python process?

Comment: As far as debugging your specific problem, you've posted on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657958/catching-a-segfault-in-python-pyodbc-cursor-fetch-causes-python-to-crash#) and on [PyODBC](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=278).  That's good.  I've taken the liberty of adding a bounty on your SO question.  As far as "debugging in general" - if you feel comfortable with MSVS - then by all means try rebuilding and see what happens.  I suspect you'll probably be sad... IMHO..

Comment: Some hints:
Install and enable [faulthandler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler/). 
Install a debugger for Windows, e.g. Visual Studio 2008.
Download and install the Python program database PDB files for your specific Python version, e.g. `python-2.7.3-pdb.zip` from `http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/`.
Rebuild pyodbc with debug symbols using msvc9 compiler. Add `/DEBUG` to `ldflags_shared` and `/Zi` to `compile_options` in `Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I was able to successfully resolve my issue by using Visual Studio 2008.  I loosely followed the steps listed here -

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t329214-debugging-python-extensions.html

And some tips on workarounds here -

[Compiling python modules whith DEBUG defined on MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236060/compiling-python-modules-whith-debug-defined-on-msvc)

Here is my version of the steps for anyone else who may encounter this problem.

1. In case you haven't already, be sure to setup the Python header and libs directories in VS

   a.  Go to **Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories**.  Be sure to add your include and libs path to the Include and Library files' path, respectively. (e.g. `C:\Python27\include`, `C:\Python27\libs`)
2. Go to your Python include folder (once again, e.g. `C:\Python27\include`) and edit `pyconfig.h`.  Comment out the line `#    define Py_DEBUG` and save.  Go to your libs folder (e.g. `C:\Python27\libs`) and make a copy of `python27.lib`.  Name the copy `python27_d.lib`.
3. Create a new project.  Choose **Win32 Project** and name it the module name (in my case `pyodbc`.  Click *Next* then choose **DLL** for **Application type** and check **Empty Project**.
4. In the Solution Explorer, right-click on Header Files and choose Add > Existing Item.  Select all of the header files that you need.  Do the same for Source Files.
5. Go to **Project > Properties**, then under **Configuration Properties** -

   a. **General** - ensure that you are using the correct **Character Set**.  For me it was `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`.  Python 3 probably needs `Use Unicode Character Set`.

   b. **Debugging** - enter the path to Python in the **Command** field.  (e.g. `C:\Python27\python.exe`).  Then set **Attach** to `Yes`.

   c. **Linker > General** - change the **Output File** to end in `.pyd` instead of `.dll`.
6. Ensure that your configuration is set to Debug.  Go to **Build > Build Solution**.
7. Open a cmd and `cd` into the directory where your `pyd` file was compiled.  Start python from the cmd window.  To attach debugger on this running python process, go back to Visual Studio and click the green play button to start debugging. You can also use Debugging -> Attach to Process...  Now go back to Python and import your module.  Play, test, and try to break it!

Answer (score 12):

### Debugging workflow with WinDbg

This workflow will create debugging information for a Release build, so you 
don't have to mess with the original include and library files of Python.

1. Download and install [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx)
2. Get the symbol files for your Python version and extract them. For Python 
   2.7.3 this would be http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3-pdb.zip.
3. Modify `setup.py` to generate debugging files. You have to add `'/Zi'` to
   `extra_compile_args` and `'/DEBUG'` to `extra_link_args`. Example:

   ```
   ext_modules  = [Extension('pyuv', sources=['src/pyuv.c'],
                             extra_compile_args=['/Zi'],
                             extra_link_args=['/DEBUG'])
                   ]
   ```
4. Build the extension as always (`python setup.py ...`).
5. Start WinDbg and specify the Symbol Search Path (Ctrl + S).

   ```
   C:\Path\To\Extension_pdb
   C:\Path\To\Extracted\python-2.7.3-pdb
   srv*;SRV*c:\tmp*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
   ```

   The last line will download and cache required symbols for Windows modules.
6. Start the Python executable (Ctrl + E). You can directly execute a 
   script or run in interactive mode.
7. Skip the initial breakpoint with "Go" (F5).
8. If there is a Segmentation fault the execution will break and you will 
   see something like *Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)*
   in the WinDbg console.
9. You can get detailed exception information by typing `!analyze -v`
   in the WinDbg console and the current stack trace with `kb`.
   [Here](https://gist.github.com/schlamar/6ce7a2efa49143be892e) is an 
   example of such an output.

You should be able to combine this approach with pyrospade's 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768458/851737) to debug with 
Visual Studio if you omit his second step and build the project with 
*Release* configuration.

A further tutorial for WinDbg could be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6084/Windows-Debuggers-Part-1-A-WinDbg-Tutorial).

Comment: I found it useful to also add `'/Od'` to `extra_compile_args` to disable optimization

Answer (score 2):

Segfaults are especially mysterious, as there is no way to trap for them from your Python code, or even to get much stacktrace information on the C side of things. One thing that *can* give you at least a little more info is to use the Google [breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) C library to report a C stack trace when the segfault occurs.

Comment: `faulthandler` (in stdlib since 3.3) can trap sigserv and print traceback

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - thanks, I still live in a 2.x world, so am unfamiliar with the newfangled stuff kids have nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try David Malcolm's tool `CPyChecker` which statically analyses C extensions for memory leaks and other bugs. The tool is [documented here](http://gcc-python-plugin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cpychecker.html).