# weird cython extension crash, cython bug?

Tags: c++, python, opencv, cython

Can anybody explain why this extension is crashing python?
I've been going crazy  with this for many hours and I can't explain it.

I have simplified my code so that it shows only the lines necessary to reproduce the crash:

I have a very simple C++ class in “test_class.h” that uses a couple of opencv types cv::Mat and cv::KeyPoint:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass();
    cv::Mat& get_current_frame_descriptors();

    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> _current_frame_points;
    cv::Mat _current_frame_descriptors;
};
```

"test_class.cpp"

```
TestClass::TestClass()
{
}

Mat& TestClass::get_current_frame_descriptors()
{
    return _current_frame_descriptors;
}
```

Then I have a cython wrapper in “test_class.pyx”:

```
 from libcpp.vector cimport vector

 cdef extern from "opencv2/core/core.hpp" namespace "cv":
    cdef cppclass Mat:
        Mat()
        int dims, rows, cols, flags

cdef extern from "test_class.h":       
    cdef cppclass TClass "TestClass":
        TClass()
        Mat _current_frame_descriptors        
        Mat& get_current_frame_descriptors()


cdef class TestClass:
    cdef TClass *TClass_ptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.TClass_ptr = new TClass()

    def get_descriptors1(self):
        m = self.TClass_ptr.get_current_frame_descriptors()
        print m.dims
        print m.rows
        print m.cols
        print m.flags

    def get_descriptors2(self):
        m = self.TClass_ptr._current_frame_descriptors
        print m.dims
        print m.rows
        print m.cols
        print m.flags
```

Notice that TClass doesn't declare _current_frame_points (the vector of KeyPoints) as it's not necessary to reproduce the crash.

I build the cython extension and I test it:

```
>>>import  test_class
>>>m = test_class.TestClass()
```

The opencv Mat _current_frame_descriptors is empty so dims, rows, and cols are zeros:

```
>>>m.get_descriptors1() 
0
0
0
1124007936

>>>m.get_descriptors2()
```

This crashes python!!!

Now, if I reverse the declaration other of _current_frame_descriptors and _current_frame_points in test_class.h then I don't get any crash!!!!

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass();
    cv::Mat& get_current_frame_descriptors();

    cv::Mat _current_frame_descriptors;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> _current_frame_points;    
};
```

Now I rebuild C++ (I build it as a lib that then I link to with the cython extension) I rebuild the cython extension and I test it

```
>>>import  test_class
>>>m = test_class.TestClass()
```

The opencv Mat _current_frame_descriptors is empty so when I do

```
>>>m.get_descriptors1() 
0
0
0
1124007936

>>>m.get_descriptors2() 
0
0
0
1124007936
```

Now I get the right result!!!

How is this possible? is this a cython bug? an opencv bug? or a C++ bug? or I'm doing something wrong?
My compiler is visual studio express 2009

Comment: Try to declare the `_current_frame_points` in the cython class declaration. AFAIK cython will *not* read the definition from the file, which means he does not know the members of the C++ class that do not appear in the cython file. Hence when doing `self.TClass_ptr._current_frame_descriptors` it is accessing the wrong memory location. Swapping the declarations solves the problem because cython is using the correct location in that case. This shouldn't happen if you add the `_current_frame_points` to the Cython declaration, since at that point it'll be able to get the correct memory location.

Comment: I just noticed "Notice that TClass doesn't declare _current_frame_points (the vector of KeyPoints) as it's not necessary to reproduce the crash." which I don't understand what it means. Do you mean that when you *do* declare it it doesn't crash or it crashes anyway? Also, when you declare it do you declare the members in the same order or not?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What I meant is that it crashed when _current_frame_points was in the declaration and it crashed when I removed it. Basically I kept removing things while it crashed until I got  that minimum set.

Comment: Actually, I found the problem. It's no bug. I was my fault, I was  mixing runtime libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason of the problem. No bugs. It was my problem. I was mixing runtime libraries :-(
A month ago I started translating some numeric python code to C++ using cython as a connection to verify consistent results. When I build the cython extension I use to get this linker warning:

LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

But I didn't know how to remove it, and the code seemed to work. I actually translated quite a bit of code in this conditions and I didn't have a problem until now. Add a few weeks break in the middle, I had completely forgotten about this.

I had to add /MDd to extra_compile_args to match my C++ library. Then I would have the problem that I needed python27_d.exe   Once I tried to build that but then I had to also build debug version of every library I use! unfeasible!

I found a trick in [How to debug C extensions for Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713701/how-to-debug-c-extensions-for-python-on-windows)
I had to comment  #define Py_DEBUG in C:\Python27\include\pyconfig.h then copy python27.exe to python27_d.exe
Now I could build with /MDd

After that I stop having the crash.